# android broadcastReceiver not working after first intent action

Tags: android

Be informed we are using broadcastreceiver for action intent to dismiss the notification dialog. It works when we use it for the first time, after that it just goes unresponsive. The first time notification pops up, we click dismiss, the action intent works just fine, but onwards from second notification, it stops working.

The code is given below:

Partial code of Android Manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup,UnusedAttribute">

<receiver android:name=".ButtonReceiver"/>
```

Button Receiver.Class (broadcast receiver)

```
public class ButtonReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("notificationId", 0);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(notificationId);
    }
}
```

Firebase.java

```
int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        int notification_id=m;
Intent buttonIntent = new Intent(this, ButtonReceiver.class);
        buttonIntent.putExtra("notificationId",notification_id);
PendingIntent btPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, buttonIntent,0);
NotificationCompat.Action action1 = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Dismiss", btPendingIntent).build();
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.asw_fcm_channel)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setTimeoutAfter(60000)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .addAction(action1)
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent2, true)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the notification id? Is it the same one that you are passing to cancel a notification?

Comment: Yes, very much. Added some more code regarding notification id.

Comment: Try Using  `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, buttonIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);` .. also u can Also change request code if required  its the second parameter which is currently 0 .